# Why don't core C or C++ texts mention sound or graphics?

Tags: c++, c, audio, graphics

How come these "Bible" type books for programming which are supposed to be comprehensive don't mention anything about programming sound or graphics?

My C programming language second edition book came in the mail today by Brian Kerninghan and Dennis Ritchie, and I thought the book was supposed to be comprehensive, but what I first noticed about it is that it is very thin. And it doesn't really seem to talk about much beyond just the basic stuff we have already learned.

So then I thought I would look in my C++ programming book by Bjarne Stroustrop, which is a lot thicker, to see what IT says about graphics and sound, and at least going by the table of contents, in 1200 plus pages, there doesn't seem to be anything on graphics or sound either.

Are graphics and sound some kind of extra subject matter that requires specialty books or something on some specific libraries or something?

Because surely, there must be some foundational stuff on sound and graphics in the core language itself, isn'tt there?

If not, where does one go to start learning about programming graphics and sound?

Comment: C and C++ have no concept of sounds or graphics.

Comment: Because that's not part of C/C++. Those are programming languages, not frameworks. You can get a book for a specific sound/graphic library to learn about it.

Comment: *"Are graphics and sound some kind of extra subject matter that requires specialty books or something on some specific libraries or something?"* Definitely yes!

Comment: Not only sounds and graphics. Machine learning, physical simulation, network communication, haptics and many other technologies are not covered

Comment: Strongly disagreeing with the decision to close this question as "Too Broad". There's enough publicly available information to put together a good, cited answer to this question.

Comment: *"where does one go to start learning about programming graphics and sound?"* falls under OT, not too broad but still. The rest is very broad anyway.

Comment: @Xirema Well, we could announce some doubts regarding the recent `std::filesystem` features.

Comment: All in all, it would clutter the C++ or C standards to cover requirements against specific hardware and operating systems, that's not the purpose of a programming language.

Comment: Leads to a great and grand question: Should a language be attached at the hip to its Standard Library?

Comment: K&R was written in 1978. The C language itself is older than that. Do you remember computers in 1978? A great many of them did not have either sound or graphics.

Comment: One of the major issues is that there is no standard for sounds or graphics.  The C and C++ languages are used on embedded systems that have no capacity for sound or graphics.  The languages are used on Desktop PCs and Desktop PCs have a wide range of graphics and sound capabilities (search the internet for PC Graphic Cards).  Although there are libraries that support graphics, they have to be upgraded when graphics technology changes (which is frequently).  The language standards are not updated frequently enough to keep up with the graphics changes.

Answer (score 6):

Sound and graphics are not part of the C or C++ programming languages. The C and C++ standards define only core languages that must be extended to provide other services.

C and C++ are, by and large, abstract programming languages. They specify a few features for input and output, which are subject to interpretation and implementation choices, but they do not specify interactions with devices, including sound systems or graphics displays. They specify features for computing with data and minimal provisions for interactions and storage.

The C and C++ standards define core languages. These core languages are extended in various ways, including:

- Providing external libraries that any kind of services, including sound and graphics features.
- Using `volatile` objects to interact with machinery, including devices connected to a processor.
- Building more features into the language by supporting additional keywords or language constructs in a compiler.

Answer (score 5):

## C++ (and C) does not have graphics libraries as part of its Standard Library

Much to the chagrin of many novice programmers.

The reasons why C++ presently lacks a Graphics Library are varied. There is a proposal for a [2d graphics library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0267r7.pdf) to be added to the C++ standard, but it failed multiple times to get added, and as of this year is more-or-less defunct.

There's some writeups on Reddit that try to go into the details of what went wrong, which I'll link below, but I'll summarize the basic issues:

First, the proposal was for functionality that, intrinsically, not all Architectures + Operating Systems could support. Any viable Graphics API needs to have some basic components that can be backed by the Operating System, things like a Surface (something to draw on), a Display, and commands for drawing arbitrary images on that surface and presenting them to the display. Lots of Operating Systems have that: Windows, Linux, MacOS, for example. But many more don't, and trying to build an API where the entire API could be rendered invalid by an Operating System that fails to provide the necessary functionality was troublesome. The philosophy of the Standard Library is that it provides functionality to all compilers that correctly implement it, and a feature that couldn't make that guarantee was inherently unsuitable.

The second problem is that there was virtually no agreement on how the library should be interfaced with. A basic 2D Graphics API like that provided by Java, Python, or (some variants of) BASIC could be implemented in a wide variety of ways, each with quite substantial upsides and downsides, and the authors of the proposal didn't seem to have a coherent vision of how it should be implemented.

In particular, modern graphics is largely a matter of heterogeneous computing, between the ways that DirectX11/OpenGL 4.x try to implement their APIs (more substantially in the former case than the latter...), or the ways that DirectX12/Vulkan represent attempts to get "as close to the metal as possible", and the C++ Standard Library lacks a lot of valuable tools for handling these kinds of functionality.

Tools like `std::future` might have been sufficient, but in my experience with graphical programming, I'm skeptical it would have been enough, and even if it was, you then have the question of whether you *want* a Graphics library in your Standard Library that's implemented in such obtuse terms. That's held back the Networking proposal for years, and even that is only getting added in C++23 because there's other library features that are going to support it, like the Executors proposal, which the Networking library is pretty much dependent on.

There's a number of other ways things went wrong, but I'll leave it at those two big ones, since not only do they explain why this specific proposal didn't go anywhere, it also explains why a lot of other ambitious proposals to do the same didn't go anywhere either—including many proposals to add Audio libraries to C++.

## So what can you do instead?

For Graphics, you need two things (at minimum):

- An API for getting Windows/Surfaces/etc. to display on
- An API for generating the images that are displayed

The former can be handled by your Operating System's native windowing api, but you can also use something like QT, GLFW, SDL, or any other api you prefer that's designed for cross-platform compatibility.

The latter can be handled by a good graphics API like OpenGL, or (if you're developing for a Windows environment) DirectX (11-). You could also use Vulkan or DirectX12 if you want to get familiar with the cutting-edge technology, although I'll warn you now that both are far more complex than their predecessors because they don't abstract anything other than the barest of basics, so be aware that it's a much steeper learning curve for those.

For Audio handling, I don't have any recommendations I can personally vouch for (my experience is more limited on that front) but there's quite a few APIs that are specifically designed for that, so just do a little research into what's available.

---

References:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/89q6wr/sg13_2d_graphics_why_it_failed/
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/89we31/2d_graphics_a_more_modest_proposal/

Answer (score 2):

Putting it simply (comment from @NathanOliver): C and C++ have no concept of sounds or graphics.

As you've guessed, graphics and sound are extra subject matter that require other types of books.

Most of these things are abstracted away from the hardware, and are usually OS-dependent.
Take, for example, `/dev/dsp` on Linux. It's a part of OSS, an abstraction that allows you to play audio. You *can* interact with it in standard C or C++, it just won't work on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

For some historical perspective, at least on C:

Once upon a time, the core C language *did not even cover I/O to files*.  The core C language covered the syntax of the language, and that was *it*. If you wanted to do I/O to files, well, you could include `<stdio.h>` and call those functions... but they were just external functions in a library, you could use them or not, it wasn't like they were part of the language or anything.  (You will probably find language in that copy of K&R you just got saying more or less what I've just said here.)

Now, when the first ANSI C Standard came out in 1989 or whenever it was, it *did* cover several of the then-standard libraries, so the functions in `<stdio.h>` (and the ones in `<string.h>`, and `<math.h>`, and several others) became a formal part of the language.  But that was a pretty significant change.

But there had never been a `<stdgraphics.h>`, so there wasn't one to standardize.  (And of course there still isn't.)  And pretty much nobody was doing computer audio in the 1970's, so that had even less of a chance.

(Unix in those early days did have a nice, simple 2D graphics library, `<plot.h>`, and there might even be a few dinosaurs besides me still using it, but I don't think anyone ever considered trying to push it as a broader standard.  Today's [GNU libplot](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/) is a descendant of it.)

Basically, C never aspired to be a "platform" language like, say, Python.  And it's now so well entrenched as a low-level, platform-independent, "systems" language that I'd say there's very little chance that any of these "higher level" functionalities will ever be added to it.

Answer (score 0):

ISO C++ does have a sound and graphics (and input) Study Group:

> SG13, HMI & I/O (Human/Machine Interface): Selected low-level output (e.g., graphics, audio) and input (e.g., keyboard, pointing) I/O primitives.

which is currently active (after being inactive).

Answer (score 0):

Audio is probably even more of a mine-field for standardisation than graphics (where, I note, nobody yet has mentioned motion video - see *Codecs* below).  There are at least these levels of abstraction it could operate at (listed from low to high), depending on the application in question:

- Raw PCM samples.
- Datastreams suitable for audio Codecs (e.g. MPEG layer III, AAC).
- MIDI - or other ways of instructing a sequencer on a note-by-note basis
- Programatic audio e.g [SuperCollider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperCollider)

**PCM Audio**

Taking the first, this is possibly the most generic and portable.  At the very minimum, it requires audio hardware (or, more commonly, a software abstraction) of a double buffer or circular buffer into which output samples are written in real-time to be output somewhere.  Lots of parameters here such as sample-rate, channel-count, sample bit-depth, latency, endianness, signed-ness, and whether a push or pull (event-driven) model is used to render buffers of data.

Low-latency audio for professional applications requires real-time threads (and thus, an operating system that provides them), and careful management of system resources.

Successful APIs are CoreAudio (MacOS, iOS only), ASIO, DirectX and whole bunch of Windows APIs (professional software invariable uses ASIO), Jack, ALSA

**Codecs**

Lots of them are proprietary and patent encumbered. Various web standards have significant difficulties specifying them - and they are far less restrictive than the ISO rules.  Not all implementations implement all of them.

**MIDI**

This is at least fairly standard (although the industry spend nearly 25+ years in replacing it).  Twenty years ago, you'd have been driving specialist synthesis hardware with this (pretty much every pre-smartphone era phone and games console had one, mostly made by Yamaha), but these days the sequencer generally drives software synthesisers, and any decent one is proprietary, commercial software. No two implementations have ever sounded the same either, which makes them largely useless for portability.

**Programmatic Audio**

At this point, you'd be *defining an entirely separate* programming language.

**Conclusions**

Good luck trying to standardise any of these - the music software industry has failed repeatedly for decades in its attempts, with much laxer standards bodies.

There's a certain irony that almost all serious audio software is implemented in C++ - often *because* it lacks any kind of abstractions for audio of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Some background on the variations of graphics support.

Historically, the only supported graphics by computers was ASCII characters.  *(Search the internet for "ASCII Art").

Graphics was developed, but had two major flavors:  bitmapped and vectored.  Some systems had a list of vectors (the math type), and drew those.  Other graphic devices used *pixels* to display images.  Even today, some graphic controllers allow you to define your own "bitmap" and have reserved cells (but they don't support line drawing).

The graphics started out as monochrome.  One foreground color and one background color, no shades between.  This was to simplify complexity and cost.  Other features that soon came into being:  shades of monochrome and a brightness attribute.  The graphics controllers were originally one bit per pixel (either on or off, the "off" being the background color).  Graphics controllers then expanded to allow more bits per pixel, monochrome still being the most popular.  You could have shades of gray and change the intensity.  Some controllers also had bits for "blinking" and other attributes.

With the cost of H/W becoming less and less, graphics controllers started taking on more advanced features:  color and bit-blit.  Now you could have 4 bits of Red, 4-bits of Green, 4-bits of Blue.  This allowed for multiple color and expanding the shading when combining the intensity bit.  The graphics controllers started having their own memory and the capability of transferring bitmap data from the CPU's memory to the graphics memory area, often called bit-blit.  The controllers advanced to allowing Boolean operations with the blitting (AND, OR, XOR, etc.).

The modern advanced graphics controllers are considered separate computers from the CPU's.  Not only do they have their own memory, but they have Cores that can be used by the CPU to perform processing in parallel.  Many of these controllers have common algorithms implemented in hardware (such as screen rotation, collision detection).  They have multiple buffers so that the CPU can draw into one buffer while the GPU displays another buffer (helps with graphic speed to support animations).

The C and C++ are *standards*.  That is, you should be able to compile a standard C language program to any platform that supports the standard.  The issue with graphics, is that there is no standard.  Some graphics controllers only support text and bitmaps, and not line drawing.  Desktop PCs have various degrees of graphics capability depend on the graphics board plugged into the system.  So, there is not much that can be standardized.  Also, graphics technology is constantly changing (improving) at a faster rate than the language standards are developed.

Lastly, let's talk about low level programming.  To get the most performance from graphics, the code needs to access the hardware directly; sometimes also exploiting features of the processor.  Any graphics API placed into the language would have to be abstract to support graphics concepts; and probably not efficient because of the subtraction.  The low level programming of the graphics hardware would still exist for performance.  The compiler writers are not graphics exports and would either use libraries or compiler for the general case.  So many combinations to support (as illustrated in the history section above).

Remember that C and C++ languages are "you only get what you pay for".  If I don't use any graphics on my embedded system, I should be able to have the compiler code without graphic support.  These languages have a wider audience than other languages that support graphics, like Java.